# Rails plugin for appointment scheduling?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

HI,
 I have a requirement in which the person A can see a calendar of Person B and check what time is the Person B available on a particular day, and book an appointment by clicking on the Available slot.
Something Like;

> Monday 21st March:
>
> 9am-10 am - Not Available
>
> 10- 11  - Available
>
> 11- 12  - Available
>
> 12- 1   - Not Available
>
> ..

I tried event_calendar plugin but it gives date only and not the time slots for each day..
Are there any plugin present for Rails?

Thanks

Comment: You might want to add more appropriate tags to your post.  Tagging it (correctly) will give it a lot more exposure.

Answer (score 2):

I see this is a bit old but I had a recent requirement for the same thing so it might help to post.

I settled on:

https://github.com/bokmann/fullcalendar-rails

Which just wraps the jquery plugin:

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/

Its an active project and worth a look.
Go through the demo's and you'll see its pretty nice.

You can style it up with bootstrap or jqueryUi themes, or you can customize yourself.

Answer (score 1):

To directly answer the question: I know of no such plugin.

But since you say this functionality is a requirement, the best way to implement this I think if just by adding models and relationships between them. It sounds like this is business logic and that should be part of your core app, but abstracted away into a plugin.